# Data cleanup array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a program that cleans up two arrays with 12 scores and gets rid of the "bonus scores" (where the denominator is 0). I've looked at similar problems, but I'm at a point in which there's three main problems that either no one seems to have or haven't been addressed. the first one is when declaring the new (not bonus) arrays in main it requires that I enter a constant value, however; the size of the arrays must change for the clean_data function to work.
the second one is when calling clean_data in main it marks "deno" and "num" as an error saying that "argument of type int * is incompatible with parameter of type int**", and the last one says that the function clean_data cannot convert argument 1 from int[12] to int*[]. 
I've been poking at this code for 3 days and looked at my professor's notes and textbook and can't find a way to fix it. please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
//prototypes for functions
void read_data(int nume[], int deno[], int size);
void report_data(int nume[], int deno[], int size);
void report_overall_grade(int nume[], int deno[], int size);
//Data cleanup
void clean_data(int *nume[], int *deno[], int size, int *notBonusNum[], int       *notBonusDen[], int &newSize);
int main()
{
    //declare constat, arrays, and variables;
    const int NUM_GRADES = 12;
    int nume[NUM_GRADES];
    int deno[NUM_GRADES];
    int newSize = 12;
    int notBonusNum[newSize];
    int notBonusDen[newSize];
    //call functions
    read_data(nume, deno, 12);
    cout << "Original scores: " << endl;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    report_data(nume, deno, 12);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    report_overall_grade(nume, deno, 12);
    //Data cleanup
    clean_data(nume, deno, 12, notBonusNum, notBonusDen, newSize);
    cout << "There are " << newSize << " scores that aren't bonuses:" << endl;
    report_data(notBonusNum, notBonusDen, newSize);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//function definitions
void read_data(int nume[], int deno[], int size)
{
    //open file
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("scores.txt");
    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    //read data
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        inputFile >> nume[count];
        inputFile >> deno[count];
    }

    inputFile.close();
}

void report_data(int nume[], int deno[], int size)
{
    int count;
    int number = 1;

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (deno[count] > 0)
        {
            int numerator = nume[count];
            int denominator = deno[count];
            double percent = (double)numerator / denominator * 100;
            cout << "Score " << number << " is " << numerator << " / " << denominator << " = " << percent << "%." << endl;

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Score " << number << " is " << nume[count] << " / " << deno[count] << " = Bonus Points!" << endl;
        }
        number++;
    }
}
void report_overall_grade(int nume[], int deno[], int size)
{
    int count;
    int totalNum = 0;
    int totalDeno = 0;
    double overallGrade;
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        totalNum += nume[count];
        totalDeno += deno[count];
    }

    cout << "Total points earned: " << totalNum << endl;
    cout << "Total points possible: " << totalDeno << endl;

    overallGrade = (double)totalNum / totalDeno * 100;

    cout << "Overall grade: " << overallGrade << endl;
}

//Data cleanup 
void clean_data(int *nume[], int *deno[], int size, int *notBonusNum[], int *notBonusDen[], int &newSize)
{
    int count;

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        int count2 = 0;
        if (deno[count] != 0)
        {
            notBonusNum[count2] = nume[count];
            notBonusDen[count2] = deno[count];
            newSize--;
            count2++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post code here, *please* remove extra consecutive blank lines. It just makes it require more scrolling to see the whole set of code.

Comment: Why does `clean_data` take a `int *nume[]` when all your other functions take a `int nume[]`?

Comment: I originally had clean_data without it, but when I do that the "=" inside the clean_data functions get the squiggly red lines under them, and I get a new error saying "void clean_data cannot convert argument 4 from int[newSize] to int*[]" one of the solutions I looked at had all four of them with *, and I wanted to see if it would work better. It doesn't really work any better, I just don't get the squiggly lines.